# Unable to load image or tab bar icon after change storyboard bundle with different locale

Tags: ios, localization, alassetslibrary

I am now using `assets.xassets` to get `images` and icons for tab bar and `UIImage`. I would like to change the `localization` and reload the storyboard immediately. I change the bundle to get different Lang.iproj, I works, but the icon and the image is missing after change bundle resources by path.

Could you please help me?

Many thanks.

---

What is the best way to change the language (including the label in storyboard) immediately without restarting application?

Comment: I don't understand **image is missing after change bundle resources by path**, as i know either you add images manually or using assets **you only need to care about image name**. it works always.

Comment: It seems like the storyboard cannot find the resource after I programmatically change the storyboard from base.iproj to fr.iproj in runtime

Comment: does it work when you switch the language using the standard language settings?

Comment: It works only when I launch the app at the first time, after I change the language in app, all of the icon and image disappear but programmatically added image still works